# Magento issue on "Manage Customers" page inside admin area

Tags: magento-1.7

I am working in a store using Magento and I got a big issue however I don't have any idea what is wrong. When I make click on "Manage Customers" in admin area, it shows me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/opositivo/developositivo/public_html/pinklemon/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 516
```

The code around that line is:

```
foreach ($attribute as $attributeItem) {
        if (isset($this->_staticFields[$attributeItem])) {
                $attrField = sprintf('e.%s', $attributeItem);
        } else {
                $attributeInstance = $this->getAttribute($attributeItem);

                if ($attributeInstance->getBackend()->isStatic()) {
                        $attrField = 'e.' . $attributeItem;
                } else {
                        $this->_addAttributeJoin($attributeItem, 'left');
                        $attrField = $this->_getAttributeFieldName($attributeItem);
                }
        }

        $fullExpression = str_replace('{{attribute}}', $attrField, $fullExpression);
        $fullExpression = str_replace('{{' . $attributeItem . '}}', $attrField, $fullExpression);
}
```

And the line 516 is:

```
if ($attributeInstance->getBackend()->isStatic()) {
```

It seems me a problem with this "getBackend()" function. During tests, I saw the following report error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:34:"Invalid attribute name: school";i:1;s:5727:"#0 /home/opositivo/developositivo/public_html/pinklemon/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1294): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Inv??lido nome ...')
```

I have searched within magento db however I didn't find any results for "school" search.

Does anyone know about that issue and can give a help to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

Add `if (!$attrInstance) return true;` before 516 line,

your code would look like this:

```
foreach ($attribute as $attributeItem) {
        if (isset($this->_staticFields[$attributeItem])) {
                $attrField = sprintf('e.%s', $attributeItem);
        } else {
                $attributeInstance = $this->getAttribute($attributeItem);

/** Add this line in code to solve the problem **/
           if (!$attrInstance) return true;


                if ($attributeInstance->getBackend()->isStatic()) {
                        $attrField = 'e.' . $attributeItem;
                } else {
                        $this->_addAttributeJoin($attributeItem, 'left');
                        $attrField = $this->_getAttributeFieldName($attributeItem);
                }
        }

        $fullExpression = str_replace('{{attribute}}', $attrField, $fullExpression);
        $fullExpression = str_replace('{{' . $attributeItem . '}}', $attrField, $fullExpression);
}
```